# Vacuum robot sensor

Tags: components, identification

Some one knows what kind of sensor is this and how it works? Is from a vacuum robot. I guess to check something on floor. I would like to connect it to Arduino.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't know what it is, what is the motivation for connecting it anywhere?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka. Just to learn. I'm not a electronics/HW man :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That appears to be some sort of fluorescent lamp.  Note that the wires to the connector are labeled IN+ and IN-, and the wires to the lamp OUT+ and OUT-.  That doesn't make sense for a sensor.  The transformer also hints at high voltage being made, as would be required for such a lamp.

It might be a germicidal UV lamp.  Those are a form of fluorescent lamp, but their function isn't available from LEDs.  That would also explain the apparent lack of phosphor coating the inside of the bulb.

Comment: oh! Thanks. At this time I'm not able to figure out any project with a germicidal UV lamp on Arduino. Nice to meed you Olin.

Comment: Olin, you are right!! Here it is: http://www.rexim.com/pages/ccfl/mccuv.html